# Trying to import a textfile into an ArrayList and then printing that ArrayLlist to an output textfile

Tags: java, arraylist, ioexception, filewriter

Basically what I am trying to do in this program is read in a textfile "dictionary.txt" that contains all of the words in a dictionary in list form. I'm trying to take the file and read it in an ArrayList and then print that array list to the output file, "output.txt". Eventually my program is going to do more, but right now I'm just basically transferring the same data from the dictionary.txt to output.txt. As of right now all the program is doing is making the output text file but not printing any data into it. I have a separate Driver class that runs the program. I tihnk my error may lay in either not reading the dictionary in the ArrayList properly or not printing the arraylist to the output file correctly. Or i may have thrown the wrong exception? I'm not sure Ive never really messed with the IO exceptions until this program. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readDictionary {

private Scanner x;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){ //going to loop as long as there is something else

        list.add(x.next());
    }
}

public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}

//private Formatter y;
private FileWriter writer;

public void outputFile(){
    try{
        writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("you have an error");
    }
}

public void addRecords(){
    for(String str: list){
        try {
            writer.write(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the **Exception** with the **complete StackTrace** in the question itself and **mark the line where the Exception occurs**, for example with a comment

Comment: You can easily debug this yourself by simply printing out either the size of the ArrayList or the elements of the ArrayList instead of writing them to a file. Also, look into the `finally` clause - it should be used to ensure that when an error is caught, the file still closes properly.

Comment: I would look into using the java `Formatter` class. i use it for something very similar and it's great.

Comment: well, I'm missing a lot information. 1) In what order do you call those methods? 2) What exception is thrown? 3) How does the dictionary look like? Simple word below word, one each line?

Comment: As of right now there aren't any errors with the program it simply doesn't print anything to the textfile like i need it to. the textfile with all the words is a simple word below word file. I would be willing to try the Formatter class is that would be easier to write the info to the file, but I've never used that before!